# Slide out nav doesn't slide out

Tags: html, css, slide, nav

I wonder why can't i say hi in the beggining of the message? It's being auto removed. Anyway i'm trying to make a css only slide out menu following this lesson: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d4P8s-mkMvs&list=PLqGj3iMvMa4L8L9p0bCpBn6A5lwKxqwqR

But for some reason it doesn't work for me. The idea is - when menu icon is clicked the checkbox is checked and menu should change it's margin-left from -200 to 0. But it doesn't.

Any help?

```css
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.004);
}

nav {
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    margin-left: -200px;
}

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #333;
    padding-top: 30px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

nav ul li {
    margin-top: 5px;    
}

nav ul li a {

    margin-left: 17px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:  #A0A0A0;
    font-size: 19px;
    text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.01) 0 0 1px;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #FFF;
}

.menuicon {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#menustate {
    margin-left: 400px;
}

#menustate:checked + .page-wrap .sidebar{
    margin-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css-1.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript-1.js"></script>
    <title>Slide nav</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="page-wrap">
        <nav class="sidebar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Cities</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        
        <label for="menustate"><p class="menuicon" href="">☰</p></label>
        <div class="check">
            <input type="checkbox" id="menustate" value="">
        </div>
    </div>   
                
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Css + operator

When using the css + operator. It needs to be a sibling directly next 
to one an other.

Added transition, makes it look better.

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.004);
}
nav {
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #333;
  padding-top: 30px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
nav ul li {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
nav ul li a {
  margin-left: 17px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #A0A0A0;
  font-size: 19px;
  text-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .01) 0 0 1px;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #FFF;
}
.menuicon {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.sidebar {
  margin-left: -200px;
  transition: margin-left 1s;
}
#menustate:checked + .sidebar {
  margin-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css-1.css">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript-1.js"></script>
  <title>Slide nav</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="page-wrap">
    <label for="menustate">
      <p class="menuicon" href="">☰</p>
    </label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="menustate" value="">
    <nav class="sidebar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Cities</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contacts</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's just what i needed

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your selector, which should be "doing the magic" is incorrect.

```
#menustate:checked + .page-wrap .sidebar
```

This will target a `.sidebar` element, inside a `.page-wrap` element which is ADJACENT to a checked `#menustate` element. This means that not only do the `#menustate` and `.page-wrap` need to be siblings, the former needs to be placed RIGHT before the latter. So something like this.

```
<input id="menustate" type="checkbox">
<div class=".page-wrap>
  <div class="sidebar"></div>
</div>
```